# How to solve this error, my project is working on linux server?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

Actually, my project is not working on the server, I have Linux based server and I got this error and one more this project working on local properly without any error.

> set_error_handler
>
> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Class 'CI_Controller' not found
>
> Filename: /home/madan16393/public_html/recallhotel/system/core/CodeIgniter.php
>
> Line Number: 366
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/madan16393/public_html/recallhotel/application/config/routes.php
>      Line: 62
>      Function: get
>
> File: /home/madan16393/public_html/recallhotel/index.php
>       Line: 629
>       Function: require_once

Comment: make sure **system** file get uploaded correctly

Comment: yes, all files uploaded correctly. I upload files 2 to 3 times but every time I got the same error.

Comment: I checked all possible solutions but not working all.

Comment: Did you define it like `Test extends CI_Controller`? Case sensitive on linux. class `Test` must also be named `Test.php`. If that is not it then there is something wrong with your install/server; most likely the former. It is not an issue with CI.

Comment: This is also in a right form because this project is working properly on XAMPP

Comment: in database.php where I can add   $db['default']['hostname'] = "mysqlhost.yourdomain.com:3310";

Comment: the project may work locally (windows) but linux requires the names to be case-sensitive. that being said, you are probably missing files. i suggest deleting everything on your remote host and uploading it again. if that doesn't fix it we can't really help you as your problem is too localized